# Mage_Log visitor observer not triggered

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, log

my problem is that viewed products are not working for guest users.
After some hours of research I found out that the VisitorId is not generated.
Then I found out that Mage_Log is responsible for this.
Especially I'm talking about some Mage_Log observer that is not triggered:

`app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php`

```
/**
 * Initialization visitor information by request
 *
 * Used in event "controller_action_predispatch"
 *
 * @param   Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return  Mage_Log_Model_Visitor
 */
public function initByRequest($observer)
{
    if ($this->_skipRequestLogging || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->setData($this->_session->getVisitorData());

    $visitorId = $this->getId();
    if (!$visitorId) {
        $this->initServerData();
        $this->setFirstVisitAt(now());
        $this->setIsNewVisitor(true);
        $this->save();
    }
    if (!$visitorId || $this->_isVisitorSessionNew()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('visitor_init', array('visitor' => $this));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Which is defined here:
`app/code/core/Mage/Log/etc/config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <log>
                    <class>log/visitor</class>
                    <method>initByRequest</method>
                </log>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
```

But since this is some Magento default stuff, I have no idea how to debug this.
All I got so far is that `controller_action_predispatch` is triggered and `<log>` is not overwritten / used by some code/community/ or code/local/ module.

Any help?

Comment: What is your issue exaclty ? you want to display logs ?

Comment: @Prince First sentence: "my problem is that viewed products are not working for guest users" - so I want to display viewed products which are by default at the right/left catalog sidebar. For example `<block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />`

Comment: You want to display this block in the right or left side bar of your category page ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter where I want to display it - it doesn't work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check store configuration **System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log**

[image: Check store configuration System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that was acutally my problem in the first place. I set the log to "Yes" or "Visitors only" and the issue of my initial post occurs.